# how to return a function from react hook which internally uses a promise to get the value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to React and want to create a react hook which returns a function and this function uses a promise internally to get the actual value. Here is my sample code -

```
export const useMyCustomHook = () => {

    let transKey = "";
    const [value, setValue] = useState("");
    const service = useContext(serviceContext);

    const getValue = (key: string) => {
        transKey = key
        return value
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (service) {
            service.GetValue(transKey).then((res: any) => {
                setValue(res);
            });
        }
    }, []);

    return getValue;
};
```

Here is the usage -

```
const getValue = useMyCustomHook()

return (
    <div className="childComponent">
        <p>Page Title: {getValue('Key1')}</p>
        <p>Page Title: {getValue('Key2')}</p>
    </div>
)
```

**I am getting the same value for each call.**

Comment: If you have multiple values you'll need multiple states; looks like an object might be better. Put another way: the issue isn't that you're "getting the same value for each call" (which may or may not be true), but that you keep overwriting a single state value with the result of each call.

Comment: First of all, you should get a linter error on improper use of `useEffect` hook that depends on `service` and `transKey` but you feed it with  no deps array.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning a function, return a value directly:

```js
export const getValue = (transKey) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const service = useContext(serviceContext);

  useEffect(
    () => { service?.GetValue(transKey).then(setValue); }, // TODO: cleanup
    [service, transKey]);

  return value;
};

// -----------------

return (
    <div className="childComponent">
        <p>Page Title: {getValue('Key1')}</p>
        <p>Page Title: {getValue('Key2')}</p>
    </div>
)
```